# How to use bash for http request?

Tags: bash, http, tcp

I get the following error when I try to use bash for HTTP request. Does anybody know how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
$ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/httpbin.org/80
$ echo -e 'GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: bash\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\nhost: http://httpbin.org\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n' >&3
$ cat <&3
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 00:43:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 524
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Host` header is incorrect. That should be a hostname, not a URL:

```
$ echo -e 'GET /get HTTP/1.1\r
User-Agent: bash\r
Accept: */*\r
Accept-Encoding: gzip\r
host: httpbin.org\r
Connection: Keep-Alive\r
\r
' >&3
```

Which results in:

```
$ cat <&3
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 00:55:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 279
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "bash",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6063c87b-09303a470da318290e856d71"
  },
  "origin": "96.237.56.197",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

---

Regarding your second question about getting your script to terminate
properly, one option is to parse the `Content-Length` header and only
read that many bytes. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/httpbin.org/80

cat <<EOF | dos2unix >&3
GET /get HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: bash
host: httpbin.org

EOF

while :;  do
    read line <&3
    line=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')
    [[ -z $line ]] && break

    if [[ $line =~ "Content-Length" ]]; then
        set -- $line
        content_length=$2
    fi
done

echo "length: $content_length"
dd bs=1 count=$content_length <&3 2> /dev/null
```

That works for this one particular test case, but it's awfully fragile
(e.g., what if there is no `Content-Length` header?).

I would just use `curl` instead of trying to use `bash` as an http
client.

Comment: I put the three commands in a script, but the script hangs there. How to let the script terminate upon finishing running the three comands?

Comment: Are the '\r's necessary? I deleted all of them. It seems still working?

Comment: I was just trying to preserve your original text. I think http technically requires `\r\n` line endings, but it's likely that many servers will work without it. Your luck may vary.

Comment: Re: termination, I've updated the question with one suggestion. There may be a better way.

Comment: Regarding the comment of using curl instead of bash. Would it make sense to use bash when there are multiple requests to sent? Does web browser keep the connection alive?

Comment: If the `Content-Length` is not available, there is no way to know all the data is sent so it can be finished? How wget/curl handle this case when the length is not known?

Comment: I suspect `curl` and `wget` simply have better networking code than `bash` and are able to respond correctly to a closed socket.